# ActiveJob::SerializationError: Unsupported argument type: Date/Class

Tags: serialization, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am getting a weird error while passing class and date to an **ActiveJob** with the **Sidekiq** adapter.

```
1] pry(main)> StripeTransactionsSyncJob.perform_later(Stripe::SyncCharges, nil, 3.days.ago.to_date)
ActiveJob::SerializationError: Unsupported argument type: Class
from /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8@immosite/gems/activejob-5.0.7.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:83:in `serialize_argument'
[2] pry(main)> StripeTransactionsSyncJob.perform_later('Stripe::SyncCharges', nil, 3.days.ago.to_date)
ActiveJob::SerializationError: Unsupported argument type: Date
from /home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8@immosite/gems/activejob-5.0.7.2/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:83:in `serialize_argument'
```

As per the [doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#supported-types-for-arguments), **ActiveJob** should support both types of arguments out of the box. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#supported-types-for-arguments) you have referenced in your post refers to the `v6.1.4` of Rails. See the version info on top-right corner on that page.

The guide for [v5.0](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_job_basics.html) doesn't explicitly specify about the arguments types supported. And looking at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.7.2/activejob/lib/active_job/arguments.rb#L65) (see below) for the version of Rails you are using i.e `5.0.7.2`

```
  def serialize_argument(argument)
    case argument
    when *TYPE_WHITELIST
      argument
    when GlobalID::Identification
      convert_to_global_id_hash(argument)
    when Array
      argument.map { |arg| serialize_argument(arg) }
    when ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      result = serialize_hash(argument)
      result[WITH_INDIFFERENT_ACCESS_KEY] = serialize_argument(true)
      result
    when Hash
      symbol_keys = argument.each_key.grep(Symbol).map(&:to_s)
      result = serialize_hash(argument)
      result[SYMBOL_KEYS_KEY] = symbol_keys
      result
    else
      raise SerializationError.new("Unsupported argument type: #{argument.class.name}")
    end
  end
```

your passed argument types `Class` and `Date` are not supported and hence you are getting `SerializationError`.

**Note: Whenever referring to the API-docs or Guide I would recommend to view them for the specific version of Rails you are using.**

Answer (score 1):

The Class/Date/DateTime/Time etc were not supported in Rails 5.0. So I need to use `String` form of data being passed to the Job.

For reference, here is the method(simplified) that does deserialization

```
def serialize_argument(argument)
  case argument
  when *[ NilClass, String, Integer, Float, BigDecimal, TrueClass, FalseClass ]
    argument
  when GlobalID::Identification
    convert_to_global_id_hash(argument)
  when Array
    argument.map { |arg| serialize_argument(arg) }
  when ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    result = serialize_hash(argument)
    result[WITH_INDIFFERENT_ACCESS_KEY] = serialize_argument(true)
    result
  when Hash
    symbol_keys = argument.each_key.grep(Symbol).map(&:to_s)
    result = serialize_hash(argument)
    result[SYMBOL_KEYS_KEY] = symbol_keys
    result
  else
    raise SerializationError.new("Unsupported argument type: #{argument.class.name}")
  end
end
```